# D3 selectAll multiple classes AND or OR

Tags: d3.js, css-selectors, selectall

I am trying to select two classes like this,

```
d3.selectAll(".class1.class2")
```

but this appears to select an element with both `class1` AND `class2`. How do I select an element by class with `class1` OR `class2` but the classes need not be mutually exclusive, so an element with both classes should also get selected.

Perhaps the solution is just,

```
 d3.selectAll(".class1")
 .........;
 d3.selectAll(".class2")
 .........;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per D3's [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selecting-elements) the selection methods accept [W3C selector strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/). If you follow this link and dig into this API you end up at section [*4.1 Selector Lists*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#grouping) of the *Selectors Level 4 Draft* which specifies:

> A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the [selector list](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#selector-list).

For your example this means the correct selector string would be `".class1,.class2"`. Have a look at the following snippet which uses this selector string to color all paragraphs having either one or both of the classes `class1` or `class2`.

```js
d3.selectAll(".class1,.class2")
  .style("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<p class="class1">class1</p>
<p class="class2">class2</p>
<p class="class3">class3</p>
<p class="class1 class2">class1 class2</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work,

```
d3.selectAll(".bar||.xAxisText")
```

Comment: It works, but it throws a warning `DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '.class1||.class2||.class3' is not a valid selector.`